# C# Mongodb. Project Json to strong type after grouping

Tags: c#, json, mongodb

This is my query:

```
db.getCollection('design_ideas').aggregate( 
  { $match : {'Deals.URL': 'warm-up-with-white'}},
  { $unwind : '$Deals' },
  { $match : {'Deals.URL': 'warm-up-with-white'}},
  {$group: {_id : '$Deals.URL', Deals: {$addToSet: '$Deals'}}}
)
```

Same query in C#:

```
_mongoDB.GetCollection<DesignCategoryMongoModel>("design_ideas")
               .Aggregate()
               .Match(BsonDocument.Parse("{'Deals.URL': 'warm-up-with-white'}"))
               .Unwind("Deals")
               .Match(BsonDocument.Parse("{'Deals.URL': 'warm-up-with-white'}"))
               .Group(BsonDocument.Parse("{_id : '$Deals.URL', Deals: {$addToSet: '$Deals'}}"))               
               .FirstOrDefault();
```

Result of the query is one document with such structure:

```
{
     _id: 'url',
      Deals: [{
              DealId: 1,
              Name: 'Name',
              Products: [...]
              ...
      }]
}
```

I know that always I get the only one `Deal` object in the Deals result array.

My c# class:

```
public class Deal
{
    public int DealId {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public IEnumerable<Product> Products {get; set;}
}
```

My question is how to project result `Json` to strong C# type and is exist way to get the only one Deal object (not array)?

Comment: http://json2csharp.com/.  `exist way to get the only one Deal object (not array)` First make your code run, then you can write utility functions to return a single object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [BsonSerializer](http://api.mongodb.com/csharp/1.0/html/14241fdf-527c-e98a-8f36-9c13f7d6577c.htm) for that

```
var MyDeals = BsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<Deal>>(aggregationResult);
```

Comment: Thanks! I've used project.